# c# how to speed up a combo box

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, combobox

How to speed up a combo box populating speed? Academically speaking, imagine that a combox box has 1 billion records to be presented. How would we maximize the speed of the program.
What other methods could I use instead of a combo box to display data?

Here are the details for my particular question:
I am using WPF event handler

```
<ComboBox Height="24" SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
 Margin="146,27,0,0" Name="emoployeeUserNameComboBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"
 Width="198" Loaded="emoployeeUserNameComboBox_Loaded"/>

private void emoployeeUserNameComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    using (ToolboxDataContext dbToolbox = new ToolboxDataContext()) {
        var query = (from x in dbToolbox.DropDownEmployeesUserNames()
                     select x.UserName).ToList();
        this.emoployeeUserNameComboBox.ItemsSource = query;
    }
```

The stored procedure above `DropDownEmployeesUserNames` is defined as

```
SELECT [UserName],Emp_Number
FROM AdminUser
ORDER BY UserName
```

It returns 14,257 rows

Comment: Seriously 14000 rows in a Combobox?

Comment: Such a combobox will be _completely_ unusable, no matter how fast it is.

Comment: Would you be better off implementing your own combobox using a virtualizing panel?

Comment: I wonder about that. For example: If I create the combo box based on user inputs. If the user presses "T" populate the combo box with all T values. If they press "Ta" populate only first two letters Ta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combo boxes are meant to contain a limited set of options.  If you wish to allow someone to select from 1 billion options, you are better served to use an autocomplete coupled with a button that brings up a popup window that allows efficient searching of the data needed to select an item.  I tend to build a pop-up with the following features:

1. A filter mechanism
2. An alpha limiter
3. Paging
4. Recently selected/popular values when there tends to be some congruency in how a user selects values

Comment: I would like the user to be able to see what are the possible users. Instead of trying to type them.

Comment: Maybe I should create a textbox that controls the results of a datagrid. Then the user can select the employee.